# Google Chrome show ajax response

Tags: google-chrome

I am using Google Chrome Developer Tools to try to see the response of some AJAX url's.

The problem is that when I click on the NETWORK TAB, then on the link, then on RESPONSE, I see this text : "THIS REQUEST HAS NO RESPONSE DATA AVAILABLE".

I have been using FIREBUG and I am 100% sure there is a response from that page.

Can somebody help with this ?

Thank you !

Comment: i have the same issue. have tried everything and am tearing out hair...

Answer (score 0):

You can try manually checking if there's a response or not
So, generally when dealing with ajax, in most cases we use the POST, You can create a 'same structured' page to handle same input/response but using Get method and print the output data as normal.

This way you can see if there's any response/errors in your script very easily